IDA virtual function identification problem
I'm reverse-engineerimg a class GD0HookRenderBaseD3D8, and in this program I found out that this class is a base class (it doesn't inherit from any class), referenced from a static library. The classinformer plug-in prompts and my manual analysis confirmed the above point of view. So I created the corresponding structure.

What is very strange is that, as you can see from the virtual table recognized by IDA, it only has 5 virtual functions. But when we repaired the sub_10032780 function, we found that this class had at least 89 (352/4+1=89) functions.

If I convert all the data between 0x100D77C4 to 0x100d7820 into function addresses, I will only add 23 more functions [(0x820-0x7c4)/4=23]. What was the reason for this?
I did an experiment, the codes are as follows:
enter image description here
enter image description here
Looking at its content below in IDA, you can see that this is different from the problem I had.
In Figure 1, it directly uses the virtual function pointer of the class to call the function, while in Figure 2, it uses the class object and then finds the virtual function table to call it.
enter image description here
Botje said via static_cast syntax, which I don't quite understand.
If you know about this problem, please help me.Thanks.

Perhaps that method uses static_cast to downcast to child class which does have that many virtual methods..

On a hunch I searched for the number 137 in the Direct3D 8 SDK and found D3DRS_LIGHTING = 137. This constant is used with the SetRenderState method, which is the 51st (eg offset 200) method of IDirect3DDevice8

Thansk，i'll look into it!

I found the answer, just change the second parameter of the function to IDirect3DDevice8*
